# Azure: VM Backup Explained

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup

I am working towards my first capture of a Linux Azure VM using the capture tool.

The first step is to run `sudo waagent –deprovision`. Running this command does the following:

> 1. Removes SSH host keys (if Provisioning.RegenerateSshHostKeyPair is 'y' in the configuration file)

Does this mean that my private/public keys will be gone and my existing server will no longer be able to SSH into it's peers without copying these keys back in place?

> 2. Clears nameserver configuration in /etc/resolv.conf

I believe my custom defined DNS names will have to be put back in place as well.

> 3. Removes the root user's password from /etc/shadow (if Provisioning.DeleteRootPassword is 'y' in the configuration file)

Not familiar with `/etc/shadow`. Will I no longer have SSH access to my server?

> 4. Removes cached DHCP client leases

I'm assuming this is harmless.

> 5. Resets host name to localhost.localdomain

I believe this is only an issue if a custom hostname was setup.

> 6. Deletes the last provisioned user account (obtained from /var/lib/waagent) and associated data

Is this an account being provisioned by the capture tool itself or by me? If latter, why so?

Comment: This really belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: If you want to backup your VM, I suggest you could use Azure Backup service, I answer the [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/849152/azure-vm-backup-explained) on serverfault. If possible, you could check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you have described is for creating an image.  This image can then be used to create multiple VMs.  **This is different than taking an already built VM and moving it to Azure as is.**

1) Yes.  You are provisioning a new VM from the "captured" image.  You really don't want multiple servers having the same private key

2) DNS in Azure is configured in the virtual network you are deploying the image.  If you have this configured correctly for your environment, this step shouldn't cause any issues

3) You will be prompted on VM creation to either provide your public key to use for root authentication or to specify a username/password you will like to use.  You will have, by default, ssh to the host machine

4) It is harmless

5) Correct.  I believe in a linux vm this is replaced by the server name you create, but I could be wrong.

6) It is giving you a clean machine (remember this is "from image") so it is cleaning up any accounts it might have created.

> Update For Comments:  Here is what Azure recommends for specialized VHDs (windows)
>
> Specialized VHD - a specialized VHD maintains the user accounts,
>   applications and other state data from your original VM. If you intend
>   to use the VHD as-is to create a new VM, ensure the following steps
>   are completed.
>
> ```
> Prepare a Windows VHD to upload to Azure. Do not generalize the VM using Sysprep.
> Remove any guest virtualization tools and agents that are installed on the VM (i.e. VMware tools).
> Ensure the VM is configured to pull its IP address and DNS settings via DHCP. This ensures that the server obtains an IP address
> ```
>
> within the VNet when it starts up.

Comment: I'm assuming that this would render my existing server useless as I have custom users, startup scripts etc. Should I be following another imaging process to create an image as a backup of my VM?

Comment: You are basically going to want to follow instructions for a specialized VHD.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized .  The issue here is you still need to prep your source VM (all steps except the generalize step at the end) and then upload the VHD and "attach" it.